# How to add a variable value for database columns named as an array?

Tags: php, laravel

```
/* Place uploaded images into appropriate columns. */
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
{
    if(Input::file('image' . $i . '.size') >= 1)
    {
        $randomName = substr( md5( rand(1,9999999) ), 1, 15);
        Input::upload('image' . $i, path('public') . 'uploads/backgrounds/', Auth::user()->username . $randomName . '.jpg');

        $wedding= Wedding::where('wedding_owner', '=', Auth::user()->username)->first();
            $wedding->image1 = $randomName;
        $wedding->save();
    }
}
```

User may upload 5 pictures. The uploaded images should be placed in `image1, image2, image3, image4 and image5 columns` in `wedding table`.

Basically,

```
$wedding->image1 = $randomName;
```

Should be something like:

```
$wedding->image{$i} = $randomName;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Having enumerated fields names always smells of a bad design

Comment: Why not take all values in loop & than save at once ?

Comment: @Rikesh Care to elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concat the name inside the `{}` :

```
$wedding->{'image' . $i} = $randomName;
```

Thus you can add dynamic fields/properties to an `object`/`stdClass` instance.

Comment: This is the answer. What's the meaning of {} in PHP? I never use them, but I often see people using { } between " " brackets.

Comment: This is not. An array have to be used instead

Comment: @Imaqtpie There are various uses of `{}`, but here it allows you to use dynamic property name.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Would like to hear why it shouldn't work, have you tested?

Comment: Here are some: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2596837/656489 , Googling will show other uses.