# Trouble writing php variables into javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 'success'=>'js: function(data) {
        $("#addToListDialog$model->product_id").dialog().dialog("close");}'
```

I'm trying to write the above piece of javascript, but can't get the right combination of curly brackets a single/double quotes in order to resolve the PHP variable. How should I be writing this?

Comment: Try wrapping your PHP variable in curly braces: `{$model->product_id}`

Comment: Can you show your full code?

Comment: You shouldn't be building JavaScript with PHP. It's A Bad Idea™. Keep your HTML in `.html` files, your CSS in `.css` files, and your JS in `.js` files. Use `[data-*]` attributes and classes if you need to pass data to JavaScript.

Comment: why are you closing the dialog as soon as you create it. if you don't want it auto opened then just use `_id').dialog({ autoOpen: false })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cleaner way:

```
'success'=>'js: function(data) {
        $("#addToListDialog'.$model->product_id.'").dialog().dialog("close");}'
```

Comment: I prefer this approach as it is cleared that the string contains a PHP variable. Embedding variables inside strings is easy to overlook, which makes it hard to debug. Also, when refactoring (e.g. Rename `$model` to `$somethingElse`), most IDEs will not rename the variable if it is within a string.

Comment: @thaJeztah One IDE will ... Komodo :P

Comment: and most that do have color coding so you cant miss the variables inside blocks of text. its about the escaping really ;)

Comment: @MarZab I agree, in this case it's more convenient. Here is a discussion on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string

Comment: @SpYk3HH Maybe should have left out 'most' LOL, *my* IDE does it as well, but I've had situations where an IDE *didn't* properly pick up the variable

Comment: @KevinHiggins to simplify the quoting, HEREDOC notation comes in handy

Comment: @thaJeztah That's true as well. They do have a tendency to ruin my indentation feng shui though.

Comment: @KevinHiggins +1 really hoping one day HEREDOC can be used **with** indentation, some kind of 'custom' quotes.

Comment: @thaJeztah That would be glorious.

Comment: and just what PHP needs, more compatibility breaking syntax and more parser complexity. whats wrong with IDE plugins, eh?

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP string must be in double quotations.

This should do the trick:

```
'success'=>"js: function(data) {
        $(\"#addToListDialog{$model->product_id}\").dialog().dialog(\"close\");}"
```