# PHP - Curly Bracket Parsing

Tags: php

so I have an array, the array is:

```
<?php
$config = array('site_name' => 'SomeName');
?>
```

Now I want to echo it.

```
<title><?php echo $config['site_name']; ?></title>
```

But I have seen some websites using:

```
<title>{site_name}</title>
```

Is it possible to do so? If so can you help me out?

Comment: This is template syntax. I guess either smarty or twig.

Comment: Search for a PHP template engine.

Comment: no you cant use it by php. You can attain this by using smarty

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php this may interest u.

Comment: you also use <?=$config['site_name']?> with short_open_tag enabled in php.ini

Comment: aconrad that was a good one, but I want something like that to shorten my code, plus other's who are suggesting me a template engine, I am making my own......

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for personal support.

Comment: I am not asking for personal support @hakre I am looking for the source of {} brackets so everyone can shorten their code and utilize the code.

Comment: You must have confused things, this is not pure PHP what you're asking about. Which btw. would is documented here: http://php.net/docs - Which brings me to the point that you should might have thought about that not finding the source might be a hint that the source is not where you think it is and this probably isn't PHP even and you should have made that more prominent while asking, otherwise it's just too broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That syntax is not a valid syntax to `echo` a statement with PHP, it's the [smarty framework](http://www.smarty.net/) who uses that, which is nothing but a template engine.

---

Also, don't confuse that syntax with something like

```
<title><?php echo "This is a {$title[0]}"; ?></title>
```

Which is a valid syntax in PHP, but you need to use the curly braces here, as you are echoing an index of an array.. For more information, you can read an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php)..

---

As you commented that you want to shorten up your codes, than an alternate way to `echo` in PHP is to use `<?=` but before that, do have a read [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/151694).

Or else, declare a `function` with shortest name like

```
function e($string) {
    echo $string;
}

e('Echo This String'); //Or
e($string);
```

Comment: I am doing this to shorten the code, not to extend the code.

Comment: @user3152750 So where am saying you to even extend your code? I just explained what you asked.. any mistakes?

Comment: He doesn't really need the curly braces there. It's needed when trying to fetch array values inside of double quote strings.

Comment: I want to just fetch the array stuff in braces {} so i dont have to write <?php bla bla you know?

Comment: @user3152750 Am not getting you... I just edited my answer, you can refer that if it helps you or simply ignore :)

Comment: Errrr I simply mean, that I want to replace the text "<?php echo $config['site_name']; ?> to just {site_name}

Comment: @user3152750 You are going too fast, learn PHP first...

Comment: Er excuse me? I do know PHP, and I am trying to widen my knowledge in PHP day by day..... :(

Comment: @user3152750 Err, I'd recommend you stick with native PHP; template engines for `{replacements}` are slower and often feature-limiting. If you can't do it with native, then you can't do it anyway.

Comment: @user3152750 Am not doubting your knowledge but you are unable to understand the construct here, you are saying that my answer is [incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185360/php-curly-bracket-parsing/21185395?noredirect=1#comment31897636_21185419) but you are asking me to explain you how to build a google search engine, without you learning relevant programming languages

Comment: ......................... @Mr.Alien