# Select data where

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am trying to select data from a database that has been selected by the user on the previous page.

I am using $_POST to get the data and have the below query

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE
  $field   LIKE'%$fieldvalue%'   AND
  $filter1 LIKE'%$filter1value%' AND  
  $filter2 LIKE'%$filter2value%' AND
  $filter3 LIKE'%$filter3value%' AND
  $filter4 LIKE'%$filter4value%' ")or die('ERROR 238 - ' . mysql_error());
```

This is bringing back the error

> ERROR 238 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' LIKE '%%'' at line 2

Can anyone help by seeing what I have done wrong?

UPDATE

The variables could be blank - how do I check this first?
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php

$q = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE 1=1";
if($field != "" or $fieldvalue != "" ){
    $q .= " and $field   LIKE'%$fieldvalue%'";
}

if($filter1 != "" or $filter1value  != "" ){
    $q .= " and $filter1 LIKE'%$filter1value%'";
}

if($filter2 != "" or $filter2value  != "" ){
    $q .= " and $filter2 LIKE'%$filter2value%'";
}

if($filter3 != "" or $filter3value  != "" ){
    $q .= " and $filter3 LIKE'%$filter3value%'";
}


if($filter4 != "" or $filter4value  != ""){
    $q .= " and $filter4 LIKE'%$filter4value%'";
}


$result=mysql_query($q)or die('ERROR 238 - ' . mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing that - still getting the same error though!

Comment: Unfortunately fixing the single quote does not answer the question.

Comment: can you post query after fixing ' quote

Comment: Sure. Updated question. How do I check if the variable is blank?

Comment: @sanirranta this works! :) Could I ask what does `WHERE 1=1` mean?

Comment: we use condition for colunm, if all variable blank then get all Record

Answer (score 0):

First things first we need to alter your code to enable some debugging of the code:

I have added curley braces as I find them easier to read. (more on those herE: [Curly braces in string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php)). I have also added backticks to the SQL which are used to mark field names.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE
`{$field}`   LIKE'%{$fieldvalue}%'   AND
`{$filter1}` LIKE'%{$filter1value}%' AND  
`{$filter2}` LIKE'%{$filter2value}%' AND
`{$filter3}` LIKE'%{$filter3value}%' AND
`{$filter4}` LIKE'%{$filter4value}% ;";

echo $sql; // this allows you to see the SQL you are making

$result=mysql_query($sql)or die('ERROR 238 - ' . mysql_error());
```

Now obviously when you want other people to use your code then you will need to comment out the `echo` line. However if you are getting `SQL` errors it helps to see the SQL. As I cannot see your SQL I am going to make a series of educated guesses and provide answers for each one.

#### Guess 1: Not setting all strings.

My gut reaction is that `$fieldvalue` is not set or is an empty string. If you don't see any content for one or more of the place holders and you see a pair of backticks or `'%%'` then the problem is that somewhere else in your code the string is not getting a value.

So for this solution check that you are building the string from your user input.

#### Guess 2: Form not supplying all the values

As you are dealing with user supplied values I hope that you have something nice and solid like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['fieldvalue']){
    $fieldvalue = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['fieldvalue']));
    if($fieldvalue == ''){
        $fieldvalue='SomeDefaulValue';
    }
}
```

For each and every value.

Personally that seems like too much work and I would use an array but that's me.

Assuming that you are not proving defaults (quite a common mistake) and the form is, for some reason, not giving you all the values you need this would also result in the same output as not setting the string.

#### Guess3: An easily overlooked string name difference

It is always worth checking that you did not set the value to `$feildvalue` and then call for `$fieldvalue` (notice the slight spelling difference.

It happens to us all (and another good argument is made for an array and some loops (less to type and get wrong).