# Need to keep curly braces in text to print to file

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this code:
 if (fwrite($handle,"

```
# $hostname.$domainname
add username $hostname.$domainname {$username}
add password $hostname.$domainname {$password}
add autoenable $hostname.$domainname {$autoenable}
add method $hostname.$domainname {$method}
add device $hostname.$domainname {$devicetype}
add encryption $hostname.$domainname {$encrypt}
add userprompt $hostname.$domainname {\"User Name:\"}
"     )
```

I need the output to actually keep the curly braces in the file I am writing to, so the output would for example look like this:

```
#host123.yahoo.com
add username host123.yahoo.com {test}
add password host123.yahoo.com {testpass}
add autoenable host123.yahoo.com {1}
add method host123.yahoo.com {ssh}
add device host123.yahoo.com {cisco}
add encryption host123.yahoo.com {3des}
add userprompt host123.yahoo.com {\"User Name:\"}
```

I have tried using double quotes and then single quotes to try and keep the braces, tried escape character \ and spent a lot of time online looking all over. From what I have read, you cannot escape a Curly brace before a variable. Confused on how the syntax should be.

ANy help would be awesome.

Comment: use double curly braces

Comment: Use this excellent answer by @cletus
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php

Comment: Short of that, I believe some use of unicode in php should work produce the curly brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use double curly braces to escape them, like this:

```
$somevar = 'fomp fomp';
$text = "This is a test of {{$somevar}}";
echo $text;
// "This is a test of {fomp fomp}"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much.

Comment: I thought y can m Mark two answers as correct. I guess you can't.  Adjusted my choice.

Answer (score 0):

By changing your quotes to `'` instead of `"`, this will enable you to use `{` inside your command. With the simple use of concatenation, you can insert your variables into the text with ease. Find an example below:

```
    $InsertDomainName = $hostname.$domainname;
if (fwrite($handle,'
    # '.$InsertDomainName.'
    add username '.$InsertDomainName.' {'.$username.'}
    '   
))
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked too, but I went with the answer above only because it was a little easier and cleaner looking. Thanks for the help.