# Is this { } php syntax?

Tags: php

I looked to a php tutorial from 2010 and I found that where I suppose to see `<?php bla bla ?>` I see something like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="{metadescription}" /> 
<meta name="keywords" content="{metakeywords}" />
```

Is this an old php syntax. I assumed that metadescription is a variable and you have to do something like this:

```
<?php echo $metadescription ?>
```

Please someone give me an idea what is happening.

Comment: Looks like a template engine to me, either server-side or client-side (hopefully such tags are not handled client-side, but I've seen it done, even though it defeats the purpose of these tags).

Comment: Is that in a PHP block?

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of [Curly braces in string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php) as these strings do not look like PHP variables.

Comment: I think that Alexander O'Mara is right, but I'm not sure, because I'm not so good at php. The book where I found this is PHP 5 e-commerce Development, but I didn't find anywhere in the book a mention about any template: Smarty or other ones. I tried the code that I downloaded and I get everything in those curly brackets on the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34940124/5678086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is smarty syntax. It is a php template engine used to separate the view. Please refer http://www.smarty.net/ for more info