# What have I done wrong with my MySql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a simple search function in PHP for my MySQL database. I've tried different tutuorials but I end up with the same result. From testing a bit with print_r I think the problem is the query, but I don't understand why it doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea? My code is following:

**html**

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
     <div class="input-field">
          <input id="search" name="search" type="search" placeholder="Search lesson plans" required>
              <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
              <i class="material-icons" id="closesearch">close</i>
     </div>
</form>
```

**php**

```
<?php

require_once("db_link.inc.php");

if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = $link->escape_string($_GET['search']);
    $query = $link->query('SELECT * FROM LessonPlans WHERE Subject LIKE "%{$search}%" OR Level LIKE "%{$search}%" OR Aim LIKE "%{$search}%" AND Language="English"');

if($query->num_rows){
    while($r = $query->fetch_object()){

    echo '<div>
        <p>'; $r->Subject; echo '</p>
    </div>';
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

**Table**

```
LessonPlans
Id | Subject | Level | Aim | Text | Language
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

/Håkan

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Hmm.. You did not use echo on `$r->Subject;`? And use double tick for your query? Please state also the error you are getting or problems you are encountering.

Comment: your echoing statement is wrong it should be echo  $r->Subject;

Comment: I get nothing when searching. I used `print_r($query)` and get this: `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 14 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 )`. Does it make any difference in what order I use `'` and `"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You did not print the `$r->Subject` inside your loop.
- You did not properly [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php) the `$search` variable to your query

Your query should look like (*if you insist on using single tick `'`*):

```
$query = $link->query('SELECT * FROM LessonPlans WHERE Subject LIKE "%'.$search.'%" OR Level LIKE "%'.$search.'%" OR Aim LIKE "%'.$search.'%" AND Language="English"');
```

but if you want to keep on using the [curly brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php):

```
$query = $link->query("SELECT * FROM LessonPlans WHERE Subject LIKE '%{$search}%' OR Level LIKE '%{$search}%' OR Aim LIKE '%{$search}%' AND Language='English'");
```

and for displaying/echoing the data:

```
echo '<div>
        <p>'.$r->Subject.'</p>
      </div>';
```

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) for the difference of single tick (`'`) and double tick (`"`).

Comment: Thanks! Works now! But How come it didn't work doing the query the other way? In the video tutorial it came out with the curly brackets. Becasue of the single ticks?

Comment: `$foo = hello; echo '$foo earth';` Displays: $foo earth.  If surrounded by double quotes it would display: hello earth.   Look at your query log.

Comment: @Håkan - Yes, it does. You can check the tutorial you're looking at again. I bet the tutorial uses double tick when it uses curly brackets.

Comment: Ah, Ok, Thanks guys. I'm new to this and I had no idea there were any difference. @Logan Wayne - Yes, the tutorial use double ticks!