# What '{$x}' stands for?

Tags: php, string, syntax

I had to take a test about php to evaluate my knowledge in the field. One of the questions was to tell, what is the output of `echo '{$x}';`? Since I've never seen this kind of brackets outside function calls, I had no idea.

What's the answer?

Comment: Since you're using single quotes it echo's `{$x}`.

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php)

Comment: Also check out the difference between single quoted strings and double quoted strings [PHP Dcs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte the issue is that in several cases I *lack* the sufficient knowledge. Not that it prevents me from answering, but I definitely need to learn about the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like it was a trick question, first to see if you know what curly braces are used for in a PHP string, **but also** to to see if you know what the difference between double and single quotes in PHP strings, where single quotes are not evaluated and double quotes are, eg:

```
$name = "bob";
echo "hello $name"; // hello bob
echo 'hello $name'; // hello $name
```

I'm guessing they were assuming you would see the curly braces, which are used to isolate a variable within a string and give that answer without looking at the quotes:

```
$place = 3;
echo "you are {$place}rd in the line"; // you are 3rd in the line
echo "you are $placerd in the line"; // error, $placerd is not defined
echo 'you are {$place}rd in the line';  // you are {$place}rd in the line
```

Comment: so `"you are {$place}rd in the line"` is equivalent to `"you are".$place."rd in the line"`?

Comment: Yeah output will be exactly the same. The curly braces are just used to separate (isolate) the PHP variable within a double quote string, so in the example above to separate the variable (`$place`) from the `"rd"` part of the string

Answer (score 1):

> When you use single quotes (**'**)  - like in this scenario: `echo '{$x}';`, The Variable `$x` is not affected in any way. This means that everything within the single quotes would be interpreted as string and `echo`ed back ***verbatim***.
>    However, if you had used double quotes instead of single quotes like so: `echo "{$x}";`, this would rather result in the evaluation of the value of `$x` and the result would be `echo`ed. See the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for more information.