# What is the difference between these PHP string interpolation syntaxes

Tags: php, interpolation

What is the difference between `"${varname}"` and `"{$varname}"` in PHP's string interpolation? *(notice the position of the `$`)*

The php docs say that you can use either, but doesn't clearly explain what the difference between these two methods is. Is there actually a difference?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2596838/3933332

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is interpolation plus variable variable (dynamic variable), meaning you can use expressions here to define the name of the variable you want to interpolate `"${func()}"` While the second one syntax is used to distinct variable from the text `"some{$variable}text"`. You can actually combine them:

```
function func(){
    return 'foo';
}
$foo = 'bar';
echo "some{${func()}}text";
```

Outputs: `somebartext`