# How to concatenate php variable with json_decoded variable

Tags: php, json

Am getting json object and receiving in php using `file_get_contents()`.

```
$getAddEntryData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

The problem is i have to concatenate php variable with received object.

If it's a php REQUEST object we are doing like this.

```
$timingsStatus = $_REQUEST['timings_'.$dayArray[$i].'_status'];
```

But how can i do with json decoded object.

i tried something like this ->.

```
$timingsStatus = $getAddEntryData->timings_.$dayArray[$i]._status;
```

Its not working, how can concat like this?.

Here is my structure of json data.

```
let data = {
        timings_enabled : this.form_data.map_timings,

        timings_mon_status : this.form_data.map_timings_mon_status,
        timings_mon_from : this.form_data.map_timings_mon_from,
        timings_mon_to : this.form_data.map_timings_mon_to,


        timings_tue_status : this.form_data.map_timings_tue_status,
        timings_tue_from : this.form_data.map_timings_tue_from,
        timings_tue_to : this.form_data.map_timings_tue_to,


        timings_wed_status : this.form_data.map_timings_wed_status,
        timings_wed_from : this.form_data.map_timings_wed_from,
        timings_wed_to : this.form_data.map_timings_wed_to,


        timings_thu_status : this.form_data.map_timings_thu_status,
        timings_thu_from : this.form_data.map_timings_thu_from,
        timings_thu_to : this.form_data.map_timings_thu_to,


        timings_fri_status : this.form_data.map_timings_fri_status,
        timings_fri_from : this.form_data.map_timings_fri_from,
        timings_fri_to : this.form_data.map_timings_fri_to,


        timings_sat_status : this.form_data.map_timings_sat_status,
        timings_sat_from : this.form_data.map_timings_sat_from,
        timings_sat_to : this.form_data.map_timings_sat_to,

        timings_sun_status : this.form_data.map_timings_sun_status,
        timings_sun_from : this.form_data.map_timings_sun_from,
        timings_sun_to : this.form_data.map_timings_sun_to

    }
```

PHP code what am trying to do.

```
$getAddEntryData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$dayArray = array('mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun');

if (isset($getAddEntryData->timings_enabled)) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($dayArray); $i++) {

        //$timingsStatus = $_REQUEST['timings_'.$dayArray[$i].'_status'];
        $timingsStatus = $getAddEntryData->timings_.$dayArray[$i]._status;

        $source = str_replace('[[TIMINGS-STATUS]]', "Available", $source);

        if ($timingsStatus == 'Open') {

           // $timingsFromTime = $_REQUEST['timings_'.$dayArray[$i].'_from'];
            $timingsStatus = $getAddEntryData->timings_.$dayArray[$i]._from;


           // $timingsToTime = $_REQUEST['timings_'.$dayArray[$i].'_to'];
            $timingsStatus = $getAddEntryData->timings_.$dayArray[$i]._to;

            $source = str_replace('[[TIMINGS-'.strtoupper($dayArray[$i]).'-STATUS]]', $timingsStatus, $source);
            $source = str_replace('[[TIMINGS-'.strtoupper($dayArray[$i]).'-FROM]]', $timingsFromTime, $source);
            $source = str_replace('[[TIMINGS-'.strtoupper($dayArray[$i]).'-TO]]', $timingsToTime, $source);

        } else {

            $source = str_replace('[[TIMINGS-'.strtoupper($dayArray[$i]).'-STATUS]]', $timingsStatus, $source);
            $source = str_replace('[[TIMINGS-'.strtoupper($dayArray[$i]).'-FROM]]', "", $source);
            $source = str_replace('[[TIMINGS-'.strtoupper($dayArray[$i]).'-TO]]', "", $source);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can you include the structure of your decoded json

Comment: @NewbeeDev edited question

Comment: Seems your json is not valid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with -

```
$timingsStatus = $getAddEntryData->{'timings_' . $dayArray[$i] . '_status'};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php will help

Answer (score 0):

to do that just change your, this function will convert your json into an array

```
$getAddEntryData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

to

```
$getAddEntryData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

so this concatination works

```
$timingsStatus = $getAddEntryData['timings_'.$dayArray[$i].'_status'];
```

Comment: this and all i have done @Newbee only porblem with concat

Comment: @AppuAmruth did you tried and does it solve? yes. that's all you have to do.

Answer (score -1):

A "JSON decoded" object, is a simple object of PHP **StdClass**.
That means you can simply use it accessing propreties (public).
If you're not used to object, you can "decode" your JSON in an associative array.
In this case, you add a second parameter to your **json_decode(string, true)**

This cannot work because PHP objects use the "arrow" -> operator to access properties/methods

**$getAddEntryData->timings_->$dayArray[$i]->_status;**

If your lost with your structure, I recommend you to always use "**var_dump($variable)**", one of the best help you can have there.

FYI, don't use $_REQUEST in PHP, but prefer POST, GET, SERVER... which are much better and always valid.