# Is it possible to add title of $currentProduct in meta title when using json & PHP?

Tags: php, json, seo

Is it possible to get the title of `$currentProduct` to display in the meta title by doing something like:

```
<?php
    $root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
    $pageTitle = "Company Name | Our Products - <?php echo  $currentProduct->title ?>";
?>   

$productTitle = $currentProduct->title;
```

Answer (score 0):

***Not sure about the order of code and the tags are correct but:***

Assuming you converted your JSON string to a JSON object, yes you can.
In PHP you have a couple of choices:
Either you continue with your $currentProject as a STDClass Object or you convert it into an array:

```
// STDClass Object (Access with 'STDObject->key' returns value)
$currentProduct = json_decode($json_string); // Converts to STDClass Object

// Array Object (Access with Array[key] returns value)
$currentProduct = json_decode($json_string, true); // Converts to Array Object
```

**With and STDClass Object:**

1:

```
// Use '{' and '}' to specify the interpreter you're dealing with an object.
$pageTitle = "Company Name | Our Products - {$currentProduct->title}"; // assuming $currentProduct is a String at least
```

2:

```
// Using ' single quotes with this case is better
// but you can't put the variable inside it. (Not that you need it in this case)
$pageTitle = 'Company Name | Our Products - '.$currentProduct->title; // Concatenate the string
```

3:

[String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) documentation

```
$pageTitle .= $currentProduct->title;
```

**And now the same but with an Array Object:**

1:

```
// Use '{' and '}' to specify the interpreter you're dealing with an object.
$pageTitle = "Company Name | Our Products - {$currentProduct['title']}"; // assuming $currentProduct is a String at least
```

2:

```
// Using ' single quotes with this case is better
// but you can't put the variable inside it. (Not that you need it in this case)
$pageTitle = 'Company Name | Our Products - '.$currentProduct['title']; // Concatenate the string
```

3:

[String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) documentation

```
 $pageTitle .= $currentProduct['title'];
```

> **Note:**
>
> For the PHP Interpreter to —take in consideration— variables inside a string you must use " double quotes.
>   And as for the curly braces:
>
> *«Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string 
>   representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the
>   expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and
>   then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will
>   only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use  {\$ to
>   get a literal {$.»*
>
> Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php).