# How to get the value on the next page from anchor tag.?

Tags: php

I need to show particular persons info on the next page `info.php` by clicking the name which is inside the anchor tag. So how can i pass the value of id of that person on the next page and retrieve data from it.

```
<tr>
    <?php 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="">'.$row['name'].'</a></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['username'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['password'].'</td>';

            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: `<a href="info.php?id=" " '.$row['id']. ' " ">` I tried this but not working

Answer (score 0):

Pass:

```
echo "<td><a href='info.php?id={$row['id']}'>" . $row['name'] . '</a></td>';
```

Get:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])
```

Comment: can u please also tell me how to save this value in a variable on the page info.php.? Should i use $_POST or $_GET method.

Comment: updated my answer, you can use $_GET, but make sure you use mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: can u pls help me undrstnd  the above code of passing value

Comment: You can add `$row['id']` variable value between quotes ( `" "` ), placing it around the braces ( `{ }` ). For understanding this you should probably read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php

Answer (score 0):

code here:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "<a href='edit-main-con.php?edit=$row[id]'>Done</a><br>";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the value that is passed through the anchor tag. The **id** is the name that contained an id:

```
$X=$_GET['ID'];
echo $X;
```