# array_combine wont work with duplicate value

Tags: php

I have two string :

```
$var1 = "1,2";
$var2 = "5,5";
```

I want output like:
`5:1` `5:2`

I have tried `explode()` with `array_combine()` but it gives output like `5:2`

My php code:

```
$res =  array_combine(explode(',', $var2), explode(',', $var1));

foreach($res as $key=>$val) {
 echo "$key:$val ";
}
```

Comment: Keys must be unique.  You cant have two `5`s.

Comment: ohh gotcha @AbraCadaver  thank you :)

Comment: plz upvote question

Comment: You might want to get in the habit of accepting answers if they solve your issue: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Array keys must be unique and with your code you have two number 5, so you will get the second one.  You could loop one array and access the other with the same key:

```
$array1 = explode(',', $var1);
$array2 = explode(',', $var2);

foreach($array2 as $key => $val) {
    echo "$val:{$array1[$key]} ";
}
```

Comment: whats the purpose of {} inside echo

Comment: Would probably work without in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php