# What does {$value} means inside of a curl post request?

Tags: php, json, curl

I have the following curl post request

```
   $Curl_Session = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POST, count($post));
        curl_setopt($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "login={$username}&password={$password}");
        curl_setopt($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
        curl_setopt($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );     
        $request = curl_exec($Curl_Session);
```

what does the use of {} means? Can this request be vulnerable to xss ( i mean the login and password parameters)?

It's a curl request with the type set to application/json

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curly braces in string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php)

Comment: Means there will be used the value of the variable that is inside {}. Read more about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

> **Complex (curly) syntax**
>
> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because it allows for the use of complex expressions.
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrap it in `{` and `}`. Since `{` can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the `$` immediately follows the `{`.

Yes, the way you're using it is vulnerable to injection. You're better passing an array of POST fields, like this:

```
curl_setopt($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['login' => $username, 'password' => $password];
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your replies and sorry if it's a duplicated questions..
So it's possible that a request like my example could be vulnerable to sql injection or xss issues?