# Notice: Array to string conversion when inserting a stdClass into a stdClass

Tags: php, stdclass

I am trying to insert data from a database into a `stdClass` but for some reason, I get a notice `Notice: Array to string conversion in data.php on line 47`.

I'm creating 2 `stdClasses`, one for each vehicle and one general that contains all of them. When I'm trying to insert the vehicle's `stdClass` into the general one I get the notice.

Here is my code (Notice I wrote where line 47 is):

```
$data = new stdClass();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tresult)) {
    $vehicle = new stdClass();
    $vehicle->name = $row['name'];
    $vehicle->position = $row['position'];

    $data->$row['name'] = $vehicle; //Line 47
}
```

What am I missing here?
Thank you

Comment: Try `$data->{$row['name']}` perhaps? see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: try a var_dump($vehicle); to see if is an array or string, regard :).

Comment: @ficuscr You're a genius... Thank you :D Write it as an answer and I'll accept it as soon as it lets me

Comment: All good. Glad you got it sorted. Hook OsDev up. `"Same is good for array element output in a double quote string. {$foo[1]}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to assign this way, because you have to interpolate the variable

`$data->{$row['name']} = $vehicle`

Comment: Thank you and ficuscr, it fixed it! I'll accept the answer just when it lets me..

Comment: Just a note for those who want to learn more about how this works, this is called [Complex Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596838/5827005)