# how do i add a named anchor to my PHP dynamic link?

Tags: php, anchor

I need add a named anchor into this code:

```
<?
echo "<a href=\"reviews-mockup2.php?category=$category&amp;keyword=" . $_REQUEST['keyword'] . "&amp;nationalpage=";
?>
```

which currently looks like this in the page:

```
http://test.usfamilyguide.com/reviews-mockup2.php?category=&keyword=&nationalpage=1
```

I tried

```
<?
     echo "<a href=\"reviews-mockup2.php?category=$category&amp;keyword=" . $_REQUEST['keyword'] . "&amp;nationalpage=" . "#named-anchor";
?>
```

and got

```
http://test.usfamilyguide.com/reviews-mockup2.php?category=&keyword=&nationalpage=#named-anchor1
```

thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting to jump to a specific element `#named-anchor1` after you click the link?

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor `<a>` tags seem to have an incorrect syntax. Refer to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).

Assuming, you are wanting it to jump to a particular section in a page; your solution should be something like this:

```
echo "<a href='reviews-mockup2.php?category={$category}&amp;keyword={$_REQUEST['keyword']}#named-anchor'>Your Anchor Name</a>";
```

What I did was: removed the `nationalpage` as I assumed thats what you were using to anchor to sections in the page, put all the PHP in [curly braces `{}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php) and finally fixed your  tag syntax as defined in the link I gave earlier. This should work to how you expect.

Any issues let me know.