# How to call a string in an array

Tags: php

I could not find the syntax anywhere in the manual .. Why this syntax works and is there a link to the manual to show this is a correct naming for a variable.

```
$who = array("World", "universe");

echo "${who[0]}"; //i cant find this syntax 
echo "$who[0]"; //works
echo "{$who[0]}" ; //works
//echo "${who}[0]"; //cant call because this treats an array as a string
//echo "${who}[0]";//cant call because this treats an array as a string
```

Comment: I suggest you start reading the documentation of the tools you use. The alternative notations of variables ist listed in there.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2596837/3392762

Answer (score -1):

Simpler:

```
<?php
$who = array("World", "universe");
echo $who[0];
```

The man page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name
>   of the variable. The variable name is case-sensitive.
>   Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
>   number of letters, numbers, or underscores.

From: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php