# How to get inner array value using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**I have this array**

```
Array
(
    [thumbnail] => Array
        (
            [width] => 150
            [height] => 150
            [crop] => 1
        )

    [medium] => Array
        (
            [width] => 300
            [height] => 300
            [crop] => 
        )

    [medium_large] => Array
        (
            [width] => 768
            [height] => 0
            [crop] => 
        )

    [large] => Array
        (
            [width] => 1024
            [height] => 1024
            [crop] => 
        )

    [twentyseventeen-featured-image] => Array
        (
            [width] => 2000
            [height] => 1200
            [crop] => 1
        )

    [twentyseventeen-thumbnail-avatar] => Array
        (
            [width] => 100
            [height] => 100
            [crop] => 1
        )

)
```

If I use print_r(array_keys($arraydata, true)) I get the value of thumbnails name but I want to get the width and height and corresponding width and height value of all. I can use `foreach` tried with keys but it did not work

Comment: `$array['thumbnail']['width']` ? just `foreach $array as $key => $data` and `var_dump $data['width']`?

Comment: display your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use 1 `foreach` and use the `$key` for the value of the thumbnails and for the value you could use the keys `width` and `height`:

```
foreach($arraydata as $key => $value) {
    echo "key: $key: width: ${value['width']} height: ${value['height']}<br>";
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/gkcXi)

Comment: why you used { infront of $ i have never used it

Comment: This [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php) has a nice explanation about the curly braces in the string.

Comment: You can also write it like this `echo "key: " . $key . " width: " . $value['width'] . " height: " . $value['height'] . "<br>";`

Answer (score 1):

```
    $height = array_combine(array_keys($ar), array_column($ar,'height'));
    $width = array_combine(array_keys($ar), array_column($ar,'width'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array['thumbnail']['width']
```

will return 150

```
$array['thumbnail']['height']
```

will return 150

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use a foreach loop, 2 in fact as you have an array within an array.

```
foreach ($array as $size => $subarr) {
    echo $size. '<br>';

    foreach ( $subarr as $name => $val ) {
        // dont want the crop information
        if ( $name == 'crop' ) continue;

        echo $name . ' = '. $val . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Output should be comething like

```
thumbnail
width = 150
height = 150

. . .
```

This may not be the format of output you really want but you can add that around this basic flow.