# Does PHP have a string function like Python's f-string function? (not str.format())

Tags: php, string, f-string

I'm new to PHP, so please excuse the question.

I was wondering if PHP had a string format function such as Python's f-strings function, not str.format(). I have seen a few posts regarding the subject, but most of the examples accepted as answers refer to Python's older way of dealing with formatted strings `str.format()`. In my case I would like to build a variable using a formatted string for example (Python):

```
f_name = "John"
l_name = "Smith"
sample = f`{f_name}'s last name is {l_name}.`
print(sample)
```

I know I can use (PHP):

```
 $num = 5;
 $location = 'tree';
 $format = 'There are %d monkeys in the %s';
 echo sprintf($format, $num, $location);
```

but what if I want to use `$format` as a variable? The main idea is to create a dynamic variable based on other variables for instance:

```
$db_type = $settings['db_type'];  # mysql
$db_host = $settings['db_host'];  # localhost
$db_name = $settings['db_name'];  # sample

var $format = "%s:host=%s; dbname=%s";

# Not sure what to do after that, but I can use string concatenation:

var $format = $db_type + ":host=" + $db_host + "; dbname=" + $db_name;
var $connection = new PDO($format, $db_user, $db_password);
```

NOTE: I'm aware that there are several ways to do string concatenation per the PHP documentation, however I was not really able to find anything like this.

Comment: Instead of echoing the sprintf result, just assign it to a variable.

Comment: Yes, use PHP template: `$f_name = "John";
$l_name = "Smith";
$sample = "{$f_name}'s last name is {$l_name}."`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can append any variable to any other variable with [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) using the dot notation:

```
$num = 5;
$location = 'tree';
$output = 'There are ' . $num . ' monkeys in the ' . $location; // There are 5 monkeys in the tree
```

Or the `.=` notation:

```
$a = "Hello ";
$b = "World";
$a .= $b; // $a now contains "Hello World"
```

You can also make use of a single string contained within **double-quotes**, which automatically evaluates the variable(s). Note that single-quotes do **not** evaluate variables:

```
$num = 5;
$location = 'tree';
echo 'There are $num monkeys in the $location'; // There are $num monkeys in the $location
echo "There are $num monkeys in the $location"; // There are 5 monkeys in the tree
```

And this works the same when assigning to variables:

```
$num = 5;
$location = 'tree';
$output = "There are $num monkeys in the $location"; // There are 5 monkeys in the tree
```

This can be further clarified with curly brackets:

```
$output = "There are {$num} monkeys in the {$location}"; // There are 5 monkeys in the tree
// OR
$output = "There are ${num} monkeys in the ${location}"; // There are 5 monkeys in the tree
```

Comment: Very clear! Apparently I was looking in the wrong spot.

Comment: So, should I put the dollar sign before or after `{`?

Comment: @Dharman -- For **most** situations it doesn't matter, though `{$var}` is slightly preferred. See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54857520/2341603)... which you yourself asked :)