# Fetching value of span tag in php & deploy in sql statement, not works

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a little problem in my code, please review it and help me.
I want to assign value of the span tag(fetched by id in html) to a php variable and then run a sql query to fetch record of the related value in the table. Here is my code.

I tried it in different ways but it not works.
I print the sql query and its absolutely right but does not show the correct result. I copied that printed sql query and paste it into phpmyadmin query section and run it there. Then it works fine and show related records. Please help

```
$regg = '<span id="modal-myvalue"></span>';
$fee_detail = "SELECT * FROM `fee_enroll` WHERE registeration = '$regg' AND mode = 'ENABLE'";
//here i print the query and its output is correct but doesn't show the correct record here.      
echo $fee_detail;
 $result_fee = mysqli_query($con, $fee_detail);
 while($row_fee = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_fee)) {
 echo $row_fee['registeration'];
 }
```

The data which i want to fetch in span tag(in id) is sent from a button through this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var ATTRIBUTES = ['myvalue'];
    $('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        var modalSelector = $target.data('target');

        ATTRIBUTES.forEach(function(attributeName) {
            var $modalAttribute = $(modalSelector + ' #modal-' + attributeName);
            var dataValue = $target.data(attributeName);

            $modalAttribute.text(dataValue || '');
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the button code is

```
<a class="btn" type=submit data-toggle="modal" data-target="#model-view" data-myvalue="<?php echo $row['registeration']; ?>">VIEW Detail</a>
```

When i print the query it shows:

```
(SELECT * FROM `fee_enroll` WHERE registeration = 'FA12-BSE-094' AND mode = 'ENABLE')
```

which works correctly in phpmyadmin query section. but not works here when i want to execute.

Comment: How come that `$regg` is `FA12-BSE-094` if you assign some markup to this variable?

Comment: When i put "FA12-BSE-094" in the query it works fine.

Comment: Where does that FA12-BSE-094 supposed to come from? How do you send it to the server?

Comment: I send value from a button and receive it via this script and send it to a modal and the above given code is in the modal in which i recieve that value in span tag(id)

Comment: Please, __do not__ post code in comments. It is __unreadable__.

Comment: please help if anyone knows about the modification in the code to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) as follows,

```
$regg = '<span id="modal-myvalue">FA12-BSE-094</span>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($regg);
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0);
var_dump($elements->nodeValue);
```

And then you can use this variable in query like below,

```
$fee_detail = "SELECT * FROM `fee_enroll` WHERE registeration = '$elements->nodeValue' AND mode = 'ENABLE'";
```

Comment: It works correctly but it has a static value (FA12-BSE-094). I need it in different value as i sending the data from a button through js.

Comment: @Archons "I need it in different value as i sending the data from a button through js " => share that code in question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert a variable like that. See this answer.

> **Complex (curly) syntax**
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use  {\$ to get a literal {$.

[Curly braces in string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php)

---

My suggestion should be to change the query string into the following:

`$fee_detail = "SELECT * FROM`fee_enroll`WHERE registeration = '{$regg}' AND mode = 'ENABLE'";`