# PHP CLI - comma-separated key/value pairs wrapped in curly braces - what are they?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

Running PHP script from cli as:

```
$ php test.php {a=1,b=2,c=3}
```

Results in `$argv` structure as:

```
[
    0 => test.php
    1 => a=1
    2 => b=2
    3 => c=3
]
```

**Question.**

1. What is the intended meaning of `{ ... }` in that case?
2. Is it a PHP thing or bash thing?
3. Is there an online documentation that describes this behaviour? (yes, I've googled already - without success)

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curly braces in string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php)

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP and everything to do with shell parameter expansion

Comment: @LelioFaieta it is not a dupe. At least not a dupe of the question you linked.

Comment: Or from the horse's mouth: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion

Comment: Doesn't appear to be bash though, no "$" before the params.  Looks like csh/tcsh.

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey a `$` isn't necessary for brace expansion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [section 3.5.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) of [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

> Brace expansion is a mechanism by which arbitrary strings may be generated. This mechanism is similar to *filename expansion*, but the filenames generated need not exist. Patterns to be brace expanded take the form of an optional *preamble*, followed by either a series of comma-separated strings or a sequence expression between a pair of braces, followed by an optional *postscript*. The preamble is prefixed to each string contained within the braces, and the postscript is then appended to each resulting string, expanding left to right.

In your case, there is no preamble or postscript, so it's just expanding to each of the elements in the list.

You can see the result by using `echo`:

```
echo {a=1,b=2,c=3}
```

Which outputs:

```
a=1 b=2 c=3
```

If you were to use a *preamble* and *postscript*:

```
echo before{a=1,b=2,c=3}after
```

You get:

```
beforea=1after beforeb=2after beforec=3after
```

I typically use this when trying to copy or move a file to a backup:

```
cp somefile.txt{,.bak}
```

Which expands to:

```
cp somefile.txt somefile.txt.bak
```

Answer (score -1):

`{}` is represented as an object in `PHP`, when `var_dump` an instance of a class, you will se it's wrapped by `{}`. There is a documentation i found which describe how to use `$argv` https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: The braces are never making it to PHP

Comment: Yes, but `PHP` actually has `object type` representation  of  `{...}`. So when `var_dump` an object, it generate infomation inside `{..}`

Comment: OK? I don't see what that has to do with this question though.

Comment: It's my assumption on how PHP converts data in `CLI`. Because PHP can `eval` the representation of object which is `{...}` to an actual object by `eval`. Your answer seems fit in this case.