# Echo specific value from Google Sheets JSON data using PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to figure out "how-to" echo out the "tbenrud@gushd.net" (red arrow pointing to it) value from [this JSON file](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1s7UCtbRY2dU3YdDu_kjnr-_y5Lh49yMHQRzgiDt8D4c/2/public/values?alt=json). I can echo `$data[feed][entry][1][id]`, but I run into trouble when I get to `gsx$emailaddress`. I assume it is because of the `$` in the label. I do not have control over the label name (created by Google Sheets).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

My Code

```
$urlSheet = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1s7UCtbRY2dU3YdDu_kjnr-_y5Lh49yMHQRzgiDt8D4c/2/public/values?alt=json';
$jsonSheet = file_get_contents($urlSheet);
$data = json_decode($jsonSheet, true);
```

Thank you!

Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use single quotes, the `$` won't trigger PHP variable interpolation.

```
echo $data['feed']['entry'][1]['gsx$emailaddress']['$t'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "escaping" the $ sign like this:

```
'gsx{$}emailaddress'
```

Comment: This is not escaping, this is a [complex curly syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596838/5407848) it will not even trigger the variable interpolation, because it is between a single quote string.