# PHP - Extract function result directly in string

Tags: php, syntax

Is it possible to call a function directly inline (and get its result) in a string in PHP?

Normally the `.` concatenate character can be used.

```
$x = "Class Name : '" . get_class($class) . "'";
```

I want to do something like this:

```
$x = "Class Name : '${get_class($class)}'";
```

Comment: you can call function if function return value

Comment: you can't, it will re-declare the function again and possibly it may show errors as `cannot re-declare yourFunction()`

Comment: Two contradicting answers, mmmm ;)

"you can call function if function return value "  - mind giving me an example please :)

  - Thanks, I am just waiting to see if he can show me an example.

Comment: @Adyson, can you confirm if it is possible to for instance use `get_class` inline (similar to what I tried) and in an example?

Comment: @CvRChameleon This notation doesn't work with a function call directly unfortunately. There are some examples of the syntax at the following link, note the "won't work" example at the bottom, which is analogous to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596838/5947043

Comment: @RohitSahu your comment makes no sense. No functions are being declared here. Your error would only occur if you, in your own code, decided elsewhere to create a function called "get_class" which of course is already the name of a built-in PHP function. That has nothing to do with this question though.

Comment: Thank you @Adyson, I am looking at those examples now.