# Associative Array and Boolean Check in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, boolean, associative-array

I'm not too sure how to call the Associative array to verify if the number is true or false because I am doing a simple checker for enrollment class. The max class capacity is 40 and the file is combined with HTML and PHP.

**I did it like this:-**

```
<?php   
     //Create the association array.
     $classInfo = array("J1" => 20 ,"J2" => 30,"J3" => 10,"J4" => 43,
                          "J5" => 40,"J6" => 45,"J7" => 15,"J8" => 34,"J9" => 10,"J10" => 45);

     $class = array_keys($classInfo);
     $totalEnroll = count($classInfo);
?>
```

**The Code:-**

```
    <table width="300" style="border: 1px solid black">
        <tr>
            <?php
                // class and enroll Lists
                echo "<td width=20>";  
                echo "Class"."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"." Enroll"."<br><hr>";
                    for($i=0; $i < $totalEnroll; ++$i) { 
                        echo $class[$i] . "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" . 
                             $classInfo[$class[$i]] . "<br>"; 
                    } 
                echo "</td>";
                
                // Enroll to check whether the classroom is full.
                echo "<td width=20>";
                    echo "Class States" . "<br><hr>";
                    for($check = 0; $check < 10; $check++){
                        if($classInfo[$totalEnroll[$check]] >= 0 && 
                           $classInfo[$totalEnroll[$check]] <= 40){
                            echo "Full";
                            echo " <br>";
                        } else {
                            echo "Not Full";
                            echo " <br>";
                        }
                    }
                echo "</td>";
            ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**The Output That I want:-**

> | Class | Enroll | Full States |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | J1 | 20 | Not Full |
> | J5 | 40 | Full |

Do check on the part say `//Enroll to check whether the classroom is full. This is where the code of the enrollment class is checked.

However, by the way, the output can it be aligned more cleanly in a table-like column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are displaying the data in two separate loops which makes it difficult to align the data, you should make it into 1 loop and use the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags around each group of items...

```
<table width="300" style="border: 1px solid black">
    <?php
        foreach ( $classInfo as $className => $enrolled )   {
            echo "<tr>";
            // class and enroll Lists
            echo "<td>{$className}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$enrolled}</td>";

            // Enroll to check whether the classroom is full.
            echo "<td>";
            if($enrolled <= 40){
                echo "Full";
            } else {
                echo "Not Full";
            }
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

(This doesn't include a header, but I'm sure you can add that).

Comment: Thank you I see... May I ask how do you know when to loop separately or in 1 loop

Comment: And why did you put this { } in here `echo "<td>{$className}</td>";`

Comment: If you need to data to be related as in this case, one loop helps link the two together.  If you want them in lists  one after the other, then 2 loops is better.

Comment: The `{}` just makes it clear what the variable is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php

Comment: Oh, I never know about this before `{ }`. Really thank you for explaining to me. I got to learn something new hehe. This helps a lot :) @Nigel Ren