# PHP - glob() returns no result when using $variable

Tags: php, foreach, text-files, glob, file-get-contents

This shows the texts to check whether it matches the format inside the curly brackets, and it does.

```
$file = file_get_contents("C:/xampp/htdocs/gomanga/data/account/Getto/favorites/favorites.txt");
       echo $file; // shows the data: Update here,Gez,Box,Corn,Asero
```

Here, putting the data manually shows my desired output.

```
$dir = glob("C:/xampp/htdocs/gomanga/central/{Update here,Gez,Box,Corn,Asero}", GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($dir as $d){
  echo $d.'<br>';
}
```

But this doesnt work, $file has the same data as the previous

```
$dire = glob("C:/xampp/htdocs/gomanga/central/{$file}", GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($f); //returns no result just Array ()
foreach($dire as $f){
  echo $f.'<br>'; //no result
  
}
```

favorites.txt will be updated by the users so I want the above code to work.  Maybe I'm reading the txt file wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the following format...

```
"C:/xampp/htdocs/gomanga/central/{$file}"
```

the braces are used to indicate to PHP that you are using a variable substitution ([Curly braces in string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php)). This means the result won't have the `{}` part in it.

To make sure they stay in the string, you can just double up on them....

```
"C:/xampp/htdocs/gomanga/central/{{$file}}"
```